# bounding and adjusting a series of values

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, optimization

I have a set of values:

-1.4,-0.4,-0.4,-0.4,1.6,0,0,0

This is only an example set of values and can change. I am looking for a way to adjust the all of the values so that the maximum a value in the series is 1 and the minimum a value could be is -1. I would all of the values in the series to be proportionally adjusted so all of the values stay proportionally the same.

Could someone let me know how to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here is one way:

Let your values be $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Divide all of the values by $\displaystyle\max_{1\le i\le n}|x_i|$.